# In XUnit moq test The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, moq, xunit

I have got problem in unit test with mocked DB context.

Error:

> The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined

Error occurs on line:

```
_bookContext.RefreshTokens.Add(new RefreshToken() { Revoked = false, UserId = user.Id, Value = refreshToken });
```

When I delete line for adding Refresh token, the test works correctly.

Code - unit test:

```
public RegisterUserCommandHandlerTest()
{
    var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BookContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TestDatabase")
                .Options;

    _bookContextMock = new Mock<BookContext>(dbContextOptions);

    var userStoreMock = new Mock<IUserStore<User>>();
    _userManagerMock = new Mock<UserManager<User>>(userStoreMock.Object,
                null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    _configuration = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
}

[Fact]
public async Task Handle_ValidRegistration_ReturnsSuccessResponse()
{
    var request = new RegisterUserCommand()
            {
                Email = "test@gmail.com",
                Password = "Testpass123!",
                Username = "testuser"
            };

    _userManagerMock.Setup(u => u.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<User>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);

    _userManagerMock.Setup(u => u.FindByEmailAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(new User() { Id = "0718a8c1-49a2-4efa-91ce-db2e5d2ef05f", Email = request.Email, UserName = "test username" });

    _configuration.Setup(c => c["Jwt:Key"]).Returns("dasdasjuioasdhioasdhjadisosayudhauchsdiyuhcvwyutrweietwgruiyegwer");

    var handler = new RegisterUserCommandHandler(_bookContextMock.Object, _userManagerMock.Object, _configuration.Object);

    var response = await handler.Handle(request, CancellationToken.None);

    Assert.False(response.Error);
    Assert.Equal("Created", response.Message);
    Assert.Equal(201, response.StatusCode);
}
```

Command:

```
public async Task<RegisterUserResponse> Handle(RegisterUserCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(new User() { Email = request.Email, UserName = request.Username }, request.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var jwtSecretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]);
                var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(request.Email);
                var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
                {
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                    {
                        new Claim("userId", user.Id),
                        new Claim("userEmail", user.Email)
                    }),
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(jwtSecretKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
                };
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                var refreshToken = TokenUtils.GenerateRefreshToken(256);
                _bookContext.RefreshTokens.Add(new RefreshToken() { Revoked = false, UserId = user.Id, Value = refreshToken });
                _bookContext.SaveChanges();
                return await Task.FromResult(new RegisterUserResponse() { Error = false, Message = "Created", StatusCode = 201, Data = new RegisterUserResponseData() { RefreshToken = refreshToken, AccessToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token)  }  });
            }
            return await Task.FromResult(new RegisterUserResponse() { Error = true, Message = result.Errors.First().Description, StatusCode = 400 });
    }
```

dbContext:

```
public class BookContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public BookContext(DbContextOptions<BookContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }

    public DbSet<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("user_tokens");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("user_logins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("user_claims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("user_roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("role_claims");
    }
}
```